# Create numerous lists dynamically from a for loop with a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create lists from a for loop if a condition is met. Initially the list will start by appending (code, date, price) from the first row (not header), if the second row code value is equal to the last code value in the list (i.e. 10C == 10C) then append those values (code, date, price) to the first list. However, if the second row does not have the same code value as the last one in the list (i.e. 11B == 10C), then create a second list and store those values there. Same goes for every other row afterwards it checks the last list created for the last code value and if the value is not the same as the code value in the current row iteration, the it will create a new list. In effect the code is segregating by code types (i.e. a list of (code, date, price) for items that have a code of 10C, a second list of (code, date, price) for items that have a code of 11B, a third list of (code, date, price) for items that have a code I of 11K, etc..

At the end I should have several list.

Here is the (input) data set:

```
code    date            price
10C     3/26/2008       115
10C     11/7/2014       154
11B     3/10/2008       144
11B     7/15/2009       176
11B     9/21/2018       225
11K     10/7/2010       845
11K     12/3/2007       516
12H     7/24/2008       258
12H     11/15/2010      337
```

Here is the desired output:

```
lst1 = [(10C, 3/26/2008, 115), (10C, 11/7/2014, 154)]
lst2 = [(11B, 3/10/2008, 144), (11B, 7/15/2009, 176), (11B, 9/21/2018, 225)]
lst3 = [(11K, 3/26/2008, 115), (11K, 11/7/2014, 154)]
lst4 = [(12H, 3/26/2008, 115), (12H, 11/7/2014, 154)]
etc...
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
with open('myfile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    n = next(reader)  # header row
    if n is not None:
        n = next(reader) # first row of data
        lst.append((n[6], n[8], n[9])) # store first row of data (code, date, price)

   for row in reader:
       data.append((n[6], n[8], n[9]))   

groups = { k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)) }

print(groups)
```

Incorrect output:

```
{'10C': [('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', 
'11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', 
'11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', etc..
```

Comment: Dynamically creating named variables is possible, but the implementation is often convoluted and the practice itself is frowned upon. Instead, use a dictionary if you need to refer to objects by name or a list of lists if you only need the index.

Comment: Can you please give me an example (using the data set I provided?)

Comment: Do not edit the question to include the answer...

Comment: @user3062459 Do not edit the question to include the answer. Once your question has received an answer, it is not fair to change the question so that that answer doesn't address the question any more. Nobody wants to get stuck endlessly editing their answer over and over again in order to keep up with a changing question. Your question was about how to group the data by item code, now your question is "why does my output have duplicates" which is a different question entirely.

Comment: @kaya3 The question was never answered correctly.

Comment: My answer was correct until you changed the question. That it did not result in correct outputs combined with the rest of your code (which wasn't even included in your question when I wrote the answer) is unrelated to what you originally asked.

Comment: As I said, you provided no data in a usable format. I tested my answer on other sample data. By the way, the later-added code in your question is not even indented properly, let alone a [mcve]. The only way `itertools.groupby` puts duplicates in the output is if there are duplicates in the input, so your new, unrelated question is *"how did the duplicates get into my input list?"* The answer is probably that you have a second loop adding the tuple `(n[6], n[8], n[9])` again for seemingly no reason, and if you got the indentation wrong then it's an inner loop, adding all your data many times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import csv
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

data = []

with open('myfile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')

    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        if index > 0:
            data.append((row[6], row[8], row[9]))


groups = { k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)) }
print(groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use-case for [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter
groups = { k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0)) }
```

This produces a dictionary where you can look up the list of items by their first component - what you referred to as the "item code".

Comment: Where would I be able to put `groups = { k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)) }` in my code?

Comment: After constructing the list of data (called `lst` in the code in your question).

Comment: I only know how to make the first list. Can you please edit your answer to show my code and your code integrated?

Comment: Your code makes the list of all the data together, so put this afterwards.

Comment: I am doing something wrong. Can you show me how to fix it? Here is the output: `{'10C': [('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008', '11536772.5'), ('10C', '3/26/2008',`

Comment: It does not match the desired output I listed above. It just repeats the same date and price. The date and price should be different.

Comment: Also there are only two records with the code 10C. Your groups variable prints 10C for all the values.

Comment: Then either there is a problem with your source data, or your code generating the list is doing something else that you haven't shown in the question. Either way, it is a different question.

Comment: Did you take my data I provided and test it?

Comment: You didn't write a [mcve] with your data in a form that anyone could do that with, so no. But `itertools.groupby` does not create duplicates of your data, so if you are getting duplicates in your output then either they exist in your input or you have some other code which is putting them there.